# How to fix SSL Handshake Error when device is connected to the network but not logged in through website to access Internet?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

On opening the Application when the device is connected to the network but not logged in to the network through web portal to access internet, My Code is having trouble with adding interceptor.

```
operator fun invoke(prefManager: PrefManager): ApiServices {

   val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
   loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

   val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
       .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .readTimeout(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .writeTimeout(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .addInterceptor(OkHttpProfilerInterceptor())
       .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)

       if (prefManager.getAccessToken() != DEFAULT) {
          val interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
             val request = chain
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(
                 "Authorization",
                 "${prefManager.getType()} ${prefManager.getAccessToken()}"
              )
              .build()
                    chain.proceed(request) // -> Error Occurring Here ...
                }
                client.addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
            }

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client.build())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(ApiServices::class.java)
        }
```

Getting the following Error Response in LogCat.

```
Process: com.fusemachines.sagisu, PID: 22011
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at com.itkacher.okhttpprofiler.OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.java:28)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at com.itkacher.okhttpprofiler.OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.java:28) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at com.itkacher.okhttpprofiler.OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpProfilerInterceptor.java:28) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Since the Error occured inside the chain call, I am not able to solve this issue.